# How to paint my row in datagridview c# for expired date?

Tags: c#, mysql, colors, datagrid, paint

For example, 7 days before and 30 days expiration day ? 
I am doing with MySQL database and C#

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var expirationDate =  DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        var sevenDayBefore = expirationDate.AddDays(-7);

        if (now > sevenDayBefore && now < expirationDate)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else if (now > expirationDate)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;    
        }
    }
```

Right here i have:
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: You need to write code for this? Did you write ? What issue you are facing with that code? Can you share that code here?

Comment: I need a method for that. I want to compare two cells from datagridview with dates and check if first column date is greater then other.

Comment: Did you debug the code and check what value you are getting in `row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()`. That where is the reason of FormatException.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your setup looks like, but for instance, if you wanted to highlight the Row Yellow When the UnitPrice Value Is Less than $10...

```
protected void HighlightCheapProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, 
GridViewRowEventArgs e)

{

    // Make sure we are working with a DataRow

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

    {

        // Get the ProductsRow object from the DataItem property...

        Northwind.ProductsRow product = 
(Northwind.ProductsRow)((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

        if (!product.IsUnitPriceNull() && product.UnitPrice < 10m)

        {

            e.Row.CssClass = "AffordablePriceEmphasis";

        }

    }

}
```

[image]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288030.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#aspnett11cstfrmcs_topic10